# Can $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] be forged to an arbitrary string?

Tags: php, security, mysqli, ip, code-injection

I have read multiple times that getting an IP from a client using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is safe, because it CAN'T be modified by user directly (only by using proxies etc) but it always returns an IP.
Until today I've received an error email from my site that mysql error occured on query which checks if an IP is banned.

Raw query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `bans` WHERE `ip`='{$ip}'
```

and getting an ip is done using

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

I didn't do any sanitizing on $ip because I assume it can't be modified by user...
And I got an email that this query failed:

```
SELECT * FROM `bans` WHERE `ip`='1'"+order+by+1--+, 111.222.111.222'
```

(**note:** I've put 111.222.111.222 instead of attackers actual IP)

My email script also takes an IP using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] so I got that "fake" IP in there too:

```
IP: 1'"+order+by+1--+, 111.222.111.222
```

Its easy to sanitize when you know it can be modified, but I want to know how is that possible ?

Comment: Did you check the related questions?

Comment: can you track this request in the server access logs? What is IP address there?

Comment: I can, the IP is normal in logs - 111.222.111.222 - - [14/Jul/2013:00:04:11 +0200] "POST /somefile.php HTTP/1.0" 200 561 "http://www.site.com/some_other_file.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101

Comment: I've checked related questions, non of them answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: So - it weren't faked. Q.E.D.

Comment: According to what you wrote, it looks like the remote address was actually detected as "1'"+order+by+1--+, 85.222.167.111". I can't tell for sure this is impossible but I doubt it very much. Could you please post your **actual** few lines of code that generate and execute the query?

Comment: $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bans` WHERE `ip`='{$ip}'");     
that is where query fails with that error, because $ip contains malicious code instead of an IP.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps you should rephrase your title as "Can $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] be forged to an arbitrary string" so that people don't try to explain how an attacker can impersonate a fake *IP address*

Comment: Okay I've changed the title ... Now I'm still trying to figure out how an attacker managed to put anything beside an IP into $ip ...

Comment: even if the remote addr has been forged, there is no way the hacker could exploit your database this way because the result of the exploit should return to the forged ip address and if this one is forged it has no destination. That's the reason i doubt the error is here. There's something else happening with your code.

Comment: That is literally everything that matters in this code, I don't use $ip variable anywhere, and whenever I use it I take it from remote_addr... Really weird ..

Comment: it is not all the code. at least connect to database omitted. As well as many other code required for the app to run.

Comment: Well I didn't include everything because there is nothing unusual there ... There is no point in showing my mysql_connect, mysql_select_db etc since its not something that could affect this + its not in the same file so showing everything could only confuse people that can try to help me. The entire project is big and complex, splitted in many files, only this thing showed a problem, and its rather separated from entire project, sitting in separate file which only connects to database and checks for ban, if IP is banned redirect to a page that displays error.

Comment: `"The entire project is big and complex"` - bingo! That's what I am aiming to.

Comment: Your Common Sense, can you please stop trolling and taking only some part of my sentences into your "troll advantage" ? Don't write anything here unless you want to help.

Comment: Please stop accusing me with no reason. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to fake.

There are two faults with your code.

1. You do **sanitize** things, by means of *thinking* if variable is "safe" or not. While you should **format** your SQL literal, leaving that burden of thinking on the **prepared statement.**
2. You have some compromised way of getting $ip. Either `$ip` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` filled unsafe way. You can find a lot of answers here on SO to help you with.

Comment: 1. I know how to sanitize variables and use prepared statements, that was not my question. Absence of prepared statements in this project are due some other reasons which are irrelevant.

2. How can getting an IP be compromised? One line above query is $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], there is not a single line between them that could get them compromised.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, you don't.